# Eclipse CDT - Content assist ordering

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, content-assist

Is there a way to set in what order the content assist proposals will show. For instance to show class's own member functions before base class member functions, to show public member functions before private member functions etc.

I have a feeling that Completion proposal filter would do this, however I only have the default one to choose from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering Eclipse's C++ Content Assist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566037/filtering-eclipses-c-content-assist)

Comment: One link that may be relevant: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg24499.html